# CloudKit Server Sending Date/Time Date as GMT +4

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I create a record via the CloudKit dashboard and set a date/time field to a time value in GMT the server sends that time back as GMT +4.

Does the CloudKit dashboard know that I am in GMT -4 and try to automatically convert the date/time I enter to GMT or is there something else I am missing?

### CloudKit Dashboard Record

[image: CloudKit Dashboard Record]

### Logging Code

```
[queryOperation setRecordFetchedBlock:^(CKRecord *record) {
        NSLog(@"date: %@", record[@"deletedDate"]);
    }];
```

### Console Output

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing the GMT+4 date? In the dashboard or a logged `NSDate` in your app's code?

Comment: @rmaddy I am logging the date I get back to the console. The CloudKit dashboard displays the date as I entered it.

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Done. You can see that 4 hours are added to the time I entered into the CloudKit dashboard. 9/27 20:00:00 to 9/28 00:00:00

Comment: Based on what you are showing, everything is as expected. Nothing is wrong. You must be in the GMT-4 (not +4) timezone (USA east coast). 9/27/15 at 8pm (20 hours) is midnight on 9/28 in GMT time. It's simply how `NSDate` gets logged - in GMT time.

Comment: @rmaddy You believe that is expected behavior? Seems confusing to me that the dashboard would show the time/date in EST and then convert that to GMT to send to the app.

Comment: It's simply a display issue. They are the same date. Use an `NSDateFormatter` in your code to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` and then log the string value. It will be in your local time - currently EDT.

Comment: Finding this thread years later, what still remains confusing is that the dashboard seems to take the date you input in your current time zone. That is, if you're in EDT, it accepts the data as in EDT. The console is correctly outputting the time converted from EDT to GMT, but nowhere does CloudKit say, "enter the date you want in your local time zone." If I'm traveling and I enter a date, does it go in as the time zone I'm in when I put the date in, or my "home" time zone? It'd be much plainer if CloudKit's web interface just said, "enter all times in GMT."